# ffmpeg command making 0 bytes file when attempting to compress mp4 video

Tags: javascript, php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php, fluent-ffmpeg

Whenever I am running this script, it compresses my MP4 video but the output is 0 bytes.

It works well for AVI & FLV format. Please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

```
 @session_start();

    @include_once("start.php");

         $command = '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i '. FILEPATH .'/video_1244579292.mp4'.' -strict -2 -crf 20 '. COMPRESSPATH .'/my_video.mp4';

        shell_exec($command);
        echo "<br><br><br>";
        echo $command;
```

Comment: Show the ull log of the MP4 execution.

Comment: I didn't get you. How I can see it?

Comment: Add `-report` to the command. Share the report file generated.

Comment: I couldn't find report file by adding -report in command. I have another command which is doing compress mp4 video but its increase the size of the compressed video. "-codec:v mpeg4 -codec:a libmp3lame -qscale:v 4 -qscale:a 5"

Comment: By increasing qscale:v value.  Search for a filename of the type `ffmpeg-YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS.log` on your whole system.

Comment: Thanks, Mulvya. I did it, now it works but its not decreasing too much what I expected. My file is 46 MB and its compressed 27MB. Can we compress more?

Comment: Not using `mpeg4`. Link to the report when you find it.

Comment: Mulvya, please tell me where I put -report in command, from the begining or at last? I am working on c-panel. Any idea where i can see that log file in cpanel folder?

Comment: You can put `-report` anywhere,

Comment: I am trying to do that but it prevents  run my command.

Comment: Hello Mulvya, I have now received log file.  Check please https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-2T7UQpCPymN9UhkwfFF482MoV5ozpJR

Comment: This is for command with `mpeg4` and output is 42MB. Need to see report for 0-byte output.

Comment: Ohkkkk...wait. 2 minute

Comment: Sorry net was slow please check this link with 0 byte. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1L4qjDsxOe4W3xcTj7lPMnOs2IVlKDq3H/view

Comment: Are u there ? @Mulvya

Comment: Add `-vf setsar=1` and check.

Comment: no its not working bro.

Comment: Mulvya, is there any other way which can make my online videos fast?  http://www.machinerytube.com/video/MjQwMw==/press-brake-videos/400-ton-x-14-used-accurpress-cnc-hydraulic-press-brake,-mdl.-740014,-flush-floor-machine,-all-above-ground,-no-pit-required!,-foot-pedal,-light-curtains,-a5056

Comment: There's no useful error message in the report to debug, but something looks wrong with the libx264 build.

Comment: So, its not possible to compress mp4 with same qualitty?

Comment: It is, but your binary is failing with no useful error message. Get another binary and try.

Comment: Check this log file. I have 1.29GB video and after compressing it showing 21.0 KB.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dg3JCte03bFbAtox0bYrSe9y-ovFVwFh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Awesome compression rate! ;)
Seriously, though, it looks like your input video may be broken in a way. Or you ffmpeg executable is. What you should do is try to execute ffmpeg manually on your file and play around with it on the command until it works as you want. And then use the result inside your php.

Comment: Your ffmpeg command is so simple there shouldn't be many problems. Since there are, I suspect a broken video file or a broken ffmpeg executable.

Comment: @TheSHEEEP you mean to say i execute this command manually?

Comment: Yes, to find out what is going wrong. As I said, play around with it until you know. This isn't really something others could do for you, as we'd just do the same.